# Can a Canadian national resident in the US use the Mobile Passport Control app to travel to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, us-residents, pre-clearance

I am a Canadian national and resident in the US (a Green Card holder).
I am unsure if I can use the new Mobile Passport Control (MPC) App for processing at US preclearance at Toronto Pearson or at US airports. The immigration lines are long in Toronto!

Comment: You could instead apply for Nexus or Global Entry

Answer (score 4):

Green card holders are not eligible to use the MPC app.

The second paragraph of [this US government CBP FAQ page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/mobile-passport-control) says that only US citizens and Canadian B1/B2 citzen visitors may use the MPC app:

> **Where can eligible travelers use MPC?**
>
> CBP uses the Mobile Passport Control (MPC) application to streamline the > processing of eligible travelers entering the United States. Eligible travelers with a smartphone or tablet may voluntarily download the Mobile Passport Control (MPC)-enabled mobile application (app) from a mobile application store (e.g., Apple App Store or Google Play Store).
>
> The MPC mobile app, is available to U.S. citizens and Canadian B1/B2 citizens visitors. MPC is currently available at the following 38 sites, including 31 U.S. International Airports, 3 Canadian Preclearance locations, and 4 seaports of entry: